# How to use object listing for condition on relation object

Tags: php, sql, content-management-system, relationship, pimcore

This question may be asked before, But i unable to find satisfiable answer. Let we have object named Product having a relation with Tags. So if we need to find products for particular Tag, As pimcore object listing work on direct on main table/view that store relations as comma seperated values in single column. So only LIKE search solution is suggested by others.

```
$entries ->setCondition("Tags LIKE " . $entries->quote("%".$tagId."%"));
```

But I think, this solution have one bigger issue If some products store tags id like 00,111,112,189 and we want to search on tag id = 11 It will return products for undesirable tag ids like 111, 112 record too.

One solution to ignore pimcore object at all and use Zend DB Calls to object_[PRODUCTCLASSID] AND object_relations_[PRODUCTCLASSID] views.

If any other solution exist to tackle issue using only Pimcore Object API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know relations are saved like this: **,00,111,112,189,**. So with comma in the beginning and the end.

This enables you to use your condition like this:

```
$entries ->setCondition("Tags LIKE " . $entries->quote("%,".$tagId.",%"));
```

Notice the comma after and before the **%** sign.

Source: [Filtering for relations via PHP API](https://pimcore.com/docs/6.x/Development_Documentation/Objects/Object_Classes/Data_Types/Relation_Types.html#page_Filtering-for-relations-via-PHP-API)

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I need to filter out only tagid = 11, I did not need 111, 112 so on.

Comment: Using above procedure works for me as expected. I have two objects, the first one has these relations ,00,11,111,112,189, the second one ,00,111,112,189, . When using WHERE Tags LIKE '%,11,%'; I get only the first object as expected. The commas after and before % sign are very important.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the amount of data it's better to use a sub-select:

```
$entries ->setCondition("o_id IN (SELECT src_id FROM object_relation_XXX where dest_id = $tagId AND fieldname = 'Tags')");
```

... replace `XXX` with the id of the class.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I wanted to add something where I just struggled and couldn't really find anything related.
If you have a Multihref, you need to add the type of object you are relating. In case of an Object (as in my case) it should look something like

```
"%,object|".$relationId.",%"
```

Maybe this saves someone some time :)